# ObjectListView Check subitem programmatically

Tags: c#, objectlistview

How can I check a sub item of an `ObjectListView` programmatically?
`CheckObject()` and `CheckObjects()` work only with root items, not with sub items.

I tried to check it with the `CheckSubItem()` method, but it doesn't work.
I also tried to load the children first and check them with `Items[x].Checked = true`.

Example Code:

```
    public void ReloadChecks(List<ExampleClass> toCheck)
    {
        List<ExampleClass> allProperties = 
        tvTreeView.Objects.Cast<ExampleClass>().ToList();

        tvTreeView.CheckObjects(toCheck.Where(x => x.Parent == null));

        foreach (ExampleClass subitem in toCheck.Where(x => x.Parent != null))
        {

            tvTreeView.CheckSubItem(subitem, tvTreeView.AllColumns[0]);

        }
}
```

ExampleClass has a list of objects as children and an object as parent. Both attributes are nullable.
The TreeView has an single columnheader:
Checkbox | Name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Illustrating your question with a [mcve] would probably help a lot to receive better answers.

Comment: I added some code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misunderstanding of "sub-items" going on here.

From your code, it seems you are dealing with a `TreeListView`. Rows that are presented when you unroll a top-level object are "children" -- not "sub-items".

For a `ListView`, "sub-items" are all the cells on a row *except* cell 0 (Microsoft's terminology, not mine).

So, this code successfully checks the top level objects:

```
tvTreeView.CheckObjects(toCheck.Where(x => x.Parent == null));
```

The following code does nothing since it tried to check a sub-item on the only item that *cannot* be sub-item (i.e. column 0):

```
tvTreeView.CheckSubItem(subitem, tvTreeView.AllColumns[0]);
```

To check all the children, but not the top level objects, you would just use `CheckObjects()` again:

```
tvTreeView.CheckObjects(toCheck.Where(x => x.Parent != null));
```

`CheckObjects()` works on any object in the control, not just top-level objects.